# How to use variables inside query in Pandas?

Tags: python, variables, indexing, pandas

I have problem quering the data frame in panda when I use variable instead of value.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
query=df2.query('cc_vehicle_line==7')
```

works fine but

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
query=df2.query('cc_vehicle_line==variable_name')
```

It throws the message that variable_name is undefined.But it is defined. I cannot use hardcoded value as I need to automate and depending of value of variable_name, select relevant rows.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `@variable_name` with `@`

```
query=df2.query('cc_vehicle_line==@variable_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ->

1. query=df2.query(f'cc_vehicle_line=="{variable_name}"')
2. query=df2.query(f"cc_vehicle_line=='{variable_name}'")
3. query=df2.query('cc_vehicle_line==@variable_name')
4. query=df2.query("cc_vehicle_line== {0}".format(variable_name))